# Android Content Provider how to query with multiple selectionArg

Tags: android, database, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I have table like below:

Students:

```
id   |  student_name
------------------
1    |  max
2    |  alex
3    |  james
```

I want to query only students which have id `1` and `3`.

```
getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI2, projection,"id=?",selectionArg,null);
```

what I have to write in `selectionArg` so i only get students with id 1 and 3 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer i found is to add `id in (?,?)` for "selection" and give "selectionArgs[]" to query. `?` signs replaced with elements inside "selectionArgs[]". You have to add `?` for each element so i did this:

```
String selection1 = DatabaseOpenHelper.COLUMN_ID + " in (";
for (int i = 0; i < selectionArgs1.length; i++) {
    selection1 += "?, ";}           
selection1 = selection1.substring(0, selection1.length() - 2) + ")";            
getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI1, projection1, selection1, selectionArgs1, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

have you tried

```
getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI2, projection,"id=1 or id=3",null,null);
```

or if you use placeholders "?" selectionArg must contain values "1" and "3"

```
getContentResolver().query(StudentContentProvider.CONTENT_URI2, projection,"id=? or id=?",selectionArg,null);
```

Comment: yes this works but number of item needed might change, o i found similar solution